# mapping aui tags to spring mvc ModelAndView object

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc, liferay-aui

I am using spring mvc for developing my portlets. Is it mandatory that we have to use spring taglibs in the jsp too? I used  and aui tags. Can I map ModelAndView object to aui tags? I need to populate the fields using the model I set from the render method. Or is there any other wrokaround for this? I also have a model bean autowired in my controller. For eg: I should be able to set the **model** in **modelandview** object and retrieve that model in jsp to **populate aui** fields.

Comment: You have to use spring tags, you cant map modelview to aui tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a bean from the controller and used the bean attribute of aui tags. It worked.`<aui:input bean="${questionnare}" ...`. This works fine for me and if bean has value, it gets prepopulated.

```
class YourModel{
 String someValue;
}
```

In the controller we add to the rendermapping method the parameter `@ModelAttribute("yourModel") YourModel yourModel`

and in the liferay jsp page, just add

```
<aui:input type="text" name="someValue"... bean="${yourModel}"/>
```

this will populate the value if it is present.

Comment: Could you add more description about your solution because it does not work for me. I'm interested in how you add bean to model and how you get it in the jsp.

Comment: If you are using liferay this will work. Or else if you are using spring tags then you can do a spring bind.

Comment: I forgot to add `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` to `portlet` tag in `liferay-portlet.xml` file. It is necessary in liferay 6.2. Thank you very much, that you edited your answer.

Comment: Just a point. You have a 'usenamespace' attribute in aui tag so that if we use usenamespace="" for a form, there wont be any namespace attached. Thus if you want namespace to be avoided only for one form it can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use @modelAttribute annotation, spring will bind the request parameters to model.